# Error with 'Open' Method, "We found a problem with some content in "xxx.xlsx". Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?

Tags: excel, vba

I use Open file method in VBA to Open xlsx. file
But I have issue that the xslx. file has error.

When I opened xlsx. file, the content of message box is: " We found a Problem with some content in ".xlsx file". Do you want to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click yes".

If i click yes, this message box appears: "Removed Records: Merge cells from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part"

So, because of error in xlsx. file, I can not Open the file in my vba code by using "Workbook.Open(application.GetOpenFilename)
Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your input file is kind of broken.

Try to open the file manually, and copy/paste the data in a new workbook, then save it again with a .xlsx format.

If you cannot open it manually, VBA will most likely not do it any better.